# While combining tables, how to make a column distinct when it has multiple entries?

Tags: sql

I'm trying to display course numbers from table *student_enrollment* and student names from table *students*, based on a distinct last_name from table *professors*. For example, there is a professor named "Wilson" - I would like to only display the courses Wilson's teaching and the students that are enrolled in these classes.

What I have so far is the following, which displays the unique course numbers that each student is enrolled in but does not take into consideration of professors.last_name:

```
SELECT students.student_name, student_enrollment.course_no
FROM students, student_enrollment, teach
WHERE students.student_no=student_enrollment.student_no 
AND student_enrollment.course_no=teach.course_no 
GROUP BY student_name,student_enrollment.course_no
```

Please see the four queried tables (students, student_enrollment, teach, professors) below for more information:

```
create table students
(
    student_no integer,
    student_name varchar(20),
    age integer
);

insert into students values (1, 'Harpreet', 19);
insert into students values (2, 'Doug', 18);
insert into students values (3, 'Abdul', 21);
insert into students values (4, 'Mohammad', 20);
insert into students values (5, 'Ralph', 19);
insert into students values (6, 'Prateek', 22);
insert into students values (7, 'Michael', 19);
insert into students values (8, 'Jack', 19);
insert into students values (9, 'Chin', 17);
insert into students values (10, '', 20);


create table courses
(
    course_no varchar(5),
    course_title varchar(20),
    credits integer
);

insert into courses values ('CS110', 'Pre Calculus', 4);
insert into courses values ('CS180', 'Physics', 4);
insert into courses values ('CS107', 'Intro to Psychology', 3);
insert into courses values ('CS210', 'Art History', 3);
insert into courses values ('CS220', 'US History', 3);

create table student_enrollment
(
    student_no integer,
    course_no varchar(5)
);

insert into student_enrollment values (1, 'CS110');
insert into student_enrollment values (1, 'CS180');
insert into student_enrollment values (1, 'CS210');
insert into student_enrollment values (2, 'CS107');
insert into student_enrollment values (2, 'CS220');
insert into student_enrollment values (3, 'CS110');
insert into student_enrollment values (3, 'CS180');
insert into student_enrollment values (4, 'CS220');
insert into student_enrollment values (5, 'CS110');
insert into student_enrollment values (5, 'CS180');
insert into student_enrollment values (5, 'CS210');
insert into student_enrollment values (5, 'CS220');
insert into student_enrollment values (6, 'CS110');
insert into student_enrollment values (7, 'CS110');
insert into student_enrollment values (7, 'CS210');


create table professors
(
    last_name varchar(20),
    department varchar(12),
    salary integer,
    hire_date date
);

insert into professors values ('Chong', 'Science', 88000, '2006-04-18');
insert into professors values ('Brown', 'Math', 97000, '2002-08-22');
insert into professors values ('Jones', 'History', 67000, '2009-11-17');
insert into professors values ('Wilson', 'Astronomy', 110000, '2005-01-15');
insert into professors values ('Miller', 'Agriculture', 82000, '2008-05-08');
insert into professors values ('Williams', 'Law', 105000, '2001-06-05');

create table teach
(
    last_name varchar(20),
    course_no varchar(5)
);

insert into teach values ('Chong', 'CS180');
insert into teach values ('Brown', 'CS110');
insert into teach values ('Brown', 'CS180');
insert into teach values ('Jones', 'CS210');
insert into teach values ('Jones', 'CS220');
insert into teach values ('Wilson', 'CS110');
insert into teach values ('Wilson', 'CS180');
insert into teach values ('Williams', 'CS107');
```

Note that there may be multiple professors teaching the same course (and there are students enrolled in the same course more than once).

If anyone has a pointer as to what I am missing here, please let me know! I'm new to SQL and have tried a few ideas unsuccessfully.

Comment: Could you provide a ficticius table of what do you want, for e.g.? I dont understand the functionality

Comment: @LeandroBardelli This table is for a school assignment - the functionality of it doesn't fully make sense to me either, since students shouldn't be enrolling in the same class multiple times.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**30 years!!** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0):

A simple and quick way to organize the sql is to use sub clause.

```
select s.*, c.*
    from student_enrollment se
    inner join student s on se.student_no = s.student_no
    inner join course c on se.course_no = c.course_no
    where course_no in (select course_no from teach where last_name = 'Wilson')
```